# resizes images on the fly

Tags: plugins, php, images, thumbnails

I'm looking for a plugin that resizes images on the fly that I can call via php. I have searched the wordpress plugins for something that does this and wasn't able to find anything that was up to date with the current wordpress version (or atleast updated in the past few months)

If I have an image url, I want to be able to call the resizer like:

`resizer(imgurl, array('w'=>100,'h'=>100,zc=>1,q=>'100'));`

It needs to be a plugin, *not* a class to be loaded via the theme.

Comment: Did you get any perfect solution this your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OTF Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/otf-regenerate-thumbnails/). Currently I'm using this with latest WP 4.2.3 and it's working fine without any issue.